# Navbar chopped off when resizing

Tags: html, css

My navbar gets chopped off from both sides whenever I resize the window, like in this picture.
[Chop chop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oITlU.png)

I want the navbar to fit the entire screen, even when the window is resized, so that all the links and logo are visible.
I tried making the width 100vw but it has no visible effect.

Here is my HTML and CSS:

```
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><div class="container"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/SP0TLzQ/broozeb.png" alt="logo" class="logo" border="0"><div class="overlay"><div class="text-test">米</div></div></div></li>
      <li><a href ="index.html">ホーム</a></li>
      <li><a href ="about.html">米さんについて</a></li>
      <li><a href ="culture.html">日本の文化</a></li>
      <li><a href="resources.html">学習の情報</a></li>
      <li><a href ="english.html">English Stuff</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>


nav {
    background-color: blue;
    border-bottom: solid #09316b;  
    white-space: nowrap;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}


nav ul li {
    
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
  line-height: 3em;
  padding: 2em 4em;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}


nav ul li .logo {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: red;
  background-color: white;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
```

I'm really sorry to ask such basic questions, but this has been troubling me for a few weeks. I very very much appreciate your help!! My webpage can be found here: https://komesannonihongotabi.neocities.org/culture.html

Answer (score 0):

This is being caused by the following CSS line:

```
nav ul li a {
    padding: 2em 4em;
}
```

Your `a` tags have a padding on left and right of `4em`. Since em is an absolute unit and not a relative one, it will stay the same on any screen size. That is, unless you change the font-size to be smaller but I don't think that would be a good solution here. Just try adding a relative unit like `%`, or use a breakpoint as follows:

```
nav ul li a {
  padding: 2em 1em;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  nav ul li a {
    padding: 2em 4em;
  }
}
```

Another, and maybe better solution to your problem would be to use a sidenav with hamburger icon. This may however be a bit complex for beginners.

Comment: I appreciate your help and explanation,  but your suggestion doesn't seem to have done anything to prevent cut-off

Comment: Even if you would remove all spacing between the list items, the content (logo and links) will never fit on smaller screens as they themselves are too wide. That's why a hamburger menu would be better for mobile screen sizes. If you really don't want to do that you could try placing all elements vertically.

Answer (score 0):

What if you remove this line **white-space: nowrap;** from **nav {}**

Before

> nav {
> background-color: blue;
> border-bottom: solid #09316b;
> **white-space: nowrap;**
> }

After:

> nav {
> background-color: blue;
> border-bottom: solid #09316b;   }

It starts to resize now. If you want more info about white space -> [Click here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp) -<

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! But that causes all the text to display vertically when resized -- and it still gets cut off

Comment: Ah okay, I removed the padding and the white-space: nowrap and it does resize properly now!

Comment: To fix that, you can remove this line: **padding: 10%;** from **nav ul li a {}**

EDIT: Oh good, you found it. Good to know and happy to help, if you have further problems with this code.